# How to measure the filegroup disk space taken during SP execution?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I regularry get an error "Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'FileGroup_Name'" while execution of one Stored Procedure. I've refactored SP a bit, but there is a problem: this error can suddenly happens on prod, and I can't repeat it on a test environment. So, the single way to test my changes - measure disk space taken in the 'FileGroup_Name' disk space.

So, the question is "How to measure the filegroup disk space taken during SP execution"?

P.S. I know it's possible to increase a space, but by some reasons that's not an appropriate solution in my current case.

Comment: And how will measuring help you? You simply do not have enough disk space. Check that your db's recovery model is set as "simple" and that you drop the temp tables as soon as you do not need them any more.

Comment: @PacoDePaco I have one SP which processes tons of data. Also, I have an alternative, which processes data by portions of 100.000 rows. I want to be sure my alternative consumes constant amount of disk space.

Comment: I see. I am not sure but I think there is no straight-away solution to measure disk usage per stored procedure. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-geek/2017/01/09/disk-space-monitoring-using-sql-server-dmv/print/) you can find how to monitor total disk usage. You can also query how much space is occupied by each tamporary table. Which would work better for you?

Comment: Your link looks appropriate, great thanks!

Comment: @PacoDePaco >>> Check that your db's recovery model is set as "simple" <<< tempdb is always in simple recovery model. It's just cannot be configured other way

Comment: @sepupic Yes but I guess that OP does not execute his  stored procedure in tempdb ;) I wanted to eliminate disk consuming issues here

Comment: @PacoDePaco And how user db recovery model is  related to tempdb overflow?

Comment: @sepupic it is to diskspace, isn't it?

Comment: @PacoDePaco Sorry, I did not understand "is to diskspace". I wonder how in your opinion different recovery model of user database can lead to tempdb overflow

Comment: @sepupic I mean if you run out of disk space completely. If you store logs at the same disk it is easy to exhaust the space in full recovery mode. I did not know if OP's problem is not related to the fact that the files of tempdb have no space left to grow on the disk. Also, he is happy with monitoring the whole disk so I do not what are we still discussing here

Comment: @PacoDePaco >>>If you store logs at the same disk<<< I store **tempdb** on separate disk

Comment: @PacoDePaco your link looked helpful but unfortunately didn't provide any result in my situation. In any case, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than monitor tempdb disk space, try to exec your sp in SSMS getting actual execution plan.

It's probably not your temporary objects to overflow tempdb, but sort/hash spills, and they'll be reported in the actual plan.

Or you can monitor when and what eats your tempdb.

For example, I use a script to monitor it based on the following view:

```
create view [dbo].[vw_tempdb_usage]
as    
select session_id,
         cast(sum(internal_objects_alloc_page_count) * 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2))as internal_objects_alloc_Gb,
         cast(sum(internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) * 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2))as internal_objects_dealloc_Gb,
         cast(sum(user_objects_alloc_page_count) * 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2))as user_objects_alloc_Gb,
         cast(sum(user_objects_dealloc_page_count) * 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2))as user_objects_dealloc_Gb,
       cast(sum(internal_objects_alloc_page_count -
                internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) * 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2))as internal_objects_diff_Gb,
       cast(sum(user_objects_alloc_page_count -
                user_objects_dealloc_page_count)* 8. /1024 /1024 as decimal(10,2)) as user_objects_diff_Gb
from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage
group by session_id
having sum(internal_objects_alloc_page_count - internal_objects_dealloc_page_count +
      user_objects_alloc_page_count - user_objects_dealloc_page_count) /1024 > 0
```

You can join it to `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_requests` by session_id and get the statement that is currently executed to see what is growing. In our environment there are internal objects that tend to overflow tempdb, and they are always caused by internal sorts. So my advice is to find tempdb spills using actual execution plan.

Comment: I already know the SP which takes the space, and these 2 approaches (with actual plan and sys.dm_db_task_space_usage) really helped me to measure various alternatives. Thanks for you help.